# Ajax call to a php file not working with 'require_once' in that file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I basically have an ajax call to a php file:

```
$("#acceptBtn").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url:"acceptOfferFunction.php",
     data: {hash2: getURLParameter('hash2')},
     success:function(result){
         alert(result);
     }
});
```

And for the sake of clarity here's the reduced version of that file illustrating the problem:

```
<?php
     session_start();   
   //require_once 'AcceptAnOfferFromEditor.php';
     echo('foo');
 ?>
```

This works, 'foo' gets alerted, but should I uncomment the `require_once` statement, it doesn't anymore.

The included file is a php class with many functions. It would be convenient to able to call them.

Comment: There might be an error in `AcceptAnOfferFromEditor.php`. Check your logs for the error. Also use browser addons for AJAX debugging such as FireBug.

Comment: can you run the file `acceptOfferFunction.php` directly on with including `require_once 'AcceptAnOfferFromEditor.php';` then post the error if you got any.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is likely an error in your required file. Enable [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to debug this:

```
<?php
    session_start();   
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require_once 'AcceptAnOfferFromEditor.php';
    echo('foo');
```

Alternatively there might be a `die()` or `exit` call in the file.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I enabled error reporting as you suggested and it turned out there was an error with another file inclusion in  'AcceptAnOfferFromEditor.php'. I've sorted it out now. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, my answer is the first thing I do when I see a dreaded `white screen of death`

Comment: I think I'll do it a lot now:).

Comment: :D don't forget to remove it when you're done! Leaving it in production code is a security risk ;)